# Xerox - How to bypass 'Replace cartridge, 0 estimated pages remain [88.40K]'

Tags: printer, cartridge

I have a **Xerox B230 laser printer** that have been working fantastically except that it refuses to print any more pages with the following error message: `Replace cartridge, 0 estimated pages remain [88.40K]`

I'm sure it has plenty of ink left in the cartridge because all pages, including the very last one came out full black with absolutely no signs of running out of toner.

I want to tell the printer to continue printing as it is very in-ecological and uneconomical to convert a working cartridge into electrical waste just because an internal counter on the printer's chip tells so.

Anyway knows a way how to bypass / reset the counter?

Comment: Laser printers don't have 'ink', they have 'toner'. Have you tried the instructions [here](https://www.support.xerox.com/en-us/article/en/2093957.html)?

Comment: Yes and it did not help and the reason is clear: the instructions are relevant for troubleshooting `after` replacing a toner. The printer remembers the P/N of the toner and it does not let you use it if it thinks it has reached EOL. Despite the fact that there is enough toner in the cartridge to continue printing :( I'd like to convince the printer to continue printing until I decide to replace the cartridge. Just like in older laser printers that didn't have a page counter.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike 20 year old lasers, modern printers want to make sure your prints will never look faded. Once the printer has decided the cartridge is empty, the only thing you can do is to replace or refill it.